# Load test Service layer with LoadRunner thru Spring Remote

Tags: spring, service, layer, loadrunner

I have N-tier application; the presentation layer remote to the service layer through Spring Remote over HTTP.  The enterprise uses Mercury LoadRunner for load testing.  My question is how can I test the Service Layer by itself using LoadRunner and Spring Remote??  I looked around and could not find documentation on how to do so.  Kindly share your experience.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time since I used this method, so I don't know if it will still work.

Record a web script and look in your proxy settings, you'll see that the web browser is pointing at localhost on port 7777. Set the Spring Remote machine's proxy server to be your VUGen machine on port 7777, it should record without problems, but you'll have to tweak your runtime settings to properly emulate a server.

If this doesn't work then you'll have to record the network traffic with a packet capture library (winpcap, pcap or Wireshark) and write your scripts by hand. This won't be hard if you understand HTTP.